# Price slider, add live price update (text)

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I am using to update/filter the price in results.
Currently it shows the updated/selected price only after releasing the slider, how can I show the price changing while moving the slider?

```
    $('#price_range').slider({
        range:true,
        min:1000,
        max:95000,
        values:[1000, 95000],
        step:500,
        stop:function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
            $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
            $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
            filter_data();
            
        }
    });


});
</script>
```

Here is the original web page [link](http://shijilt8.sg-host.com/latest-mobile-phones/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jQueryUI slider:

Check out the "slide" function, which is triggered during the sliding process.
This might solve your problem.

https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide

```
    $('#price_range').slider({

        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        //update price here
        }
    });
```